# MySQL - GROUP By and DISTINCT, but return all rows?

Tags: mysql

Beginner at self-learning MySql..I need to bring back ALL rows where parent_ids match, but year doesn't. Problem is, GROUP BY returns only one line for each parent_id, and I want all (so, i've been using 2 queries, and pasting results from first into the second) How can I do this in one query?

I have:

```
id  parent_id   year
aa1 aa          2010
aa3 aa          2011
bb1 bb          2010
bb2 bb          2011
cc1 cc          2010
cc2 cc          2010
```

I need returned:

```
id  parent_id   year
aa1 aa          2010
aa3 aa          2011
bb1 bb          2010
bb2 bb          2011
```

Current first query:

```
SELECT id, name, `year`, parent_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `year`) > 1
```

And then I paste my results into a simple select query using IN:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, name, `year`
FROM t1
WHERE parent_id IN ('......',')
```

Answer (score 1):

One option might be using a subquery. For example:

```
SELECT id, name, year, parent_id
FROM t1
WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT parent_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) > 1)
```

You could also use a view if this is going to be queried more than once.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Answer (score 1):

When ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode is not enabled

```
SELECT id, parent_id, `year`
FROM test
GROUP BY parent_id, `year`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

When ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode is enabled

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id), parent_id, `year`
FROM test
GROUP BY parent_id, `year`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Returned result is

```
+---------------+-----------+------+
| ANY_VALUE(id) | parent_id | year |
+---------------+-----------+------+
| aa1           | aa        | 2010 |
| aa3           | aa        | 2011 |
| bb1           | bb        | 2010 |
| bb2           | bb        | 2011 |
+---------------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY can be disabled even in 5.7 or above, so any_value() is useful; but it is still violation of standard sql behaviour

Comment: Correct. Removed reference to MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id, parent_id, year
    FROM  t1
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  parent_id
            FROM  t1
            GROUP BY  parent_id
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT year) > 1 ) AS b USING(parent_id
      );
```

(JOIN is much more efficient than `IN ( SELECT ... )`, assuming `parent_id` is indexed.)

Or you might find GROUP_CONCAT more interesting:

```
SELECT  parent_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year) AS years
    FROM  t1;
    GROUP BY  parent_id
    HAVING  LENGTH(years) > 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select a.id , a.parent_id , a.year
from t1 a join t1 b
on a.id <> b.id and a.parent_id=b.parent_id and a.year<>b.year;
```